# How to send raw bits over an Ethernet cable without using frames?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ethernet

I am trying to send raw bits over an Ethernet cable without using any protocol, even without an Ethernet frame. I realize that this data won't really go anywhere as it will not have a receiving MAC address, but this is purely educational.

I know I can create a socket but it always encapsulates my data in an Ethernet frame. Does this mean I would have to write raw data somehow to the port itself?

This is a pseudo example of how I send data by creating a socket.

```
int main()
{
    char *request = "GET / HTTP/1.1";

    socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    write(new_socket , request , strlen(request));
}
```

Comment: Most ethernet interfaces do the framing for you, and it may be impossible to skip that with modern gear. If it is possible with your interface, then you will need to manipulate the hardware directly. I seriously doubt what you have will work for that.

Comment: `AF_INET` means ipv4 and `SOCK_STREAM` means TCP. Don't you want like `AF_RAW` and `SOCK_RAW`? My internet search tells me `AF_RAW` is something from bsd, I see linux has `AF_UNSPEC`.

Comment: SOCK_STREAM will add a TCP header.  You probably want something like SOCK_RAW.

Comment: By the way, understand that you do not send bits on the wire, you send symbols. There are more bits sent than bits you are sending because of the translation to symbols. Depending on the ethernet standard you are using, it could be five bits for every four bits, or some other ratio.

Comment: SOCK_RAW gives you access to sending raw packets, but there is no defined way of sending raw bytes on the wire.